# How to get Firebase data only key without values?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have 3 tables [users, tracks, trackLikers]. when user like a track it added to trackLikers like this.

```
tracklikers
     703486
          AXweXLKIQiQYmwia5TbvNbSLk472: Alex
          AXweXLKIQiQYmwia5TbvNbSLk472: John
    704875
          AXweXLKIQiQYmwia5TbvNbSLk472: Alex
```

Now i want to get how many tracks "Alex" likes. So i do it like this.

`dbReference.child("tracklikers").orderByChild("AXweXLKIQiQYmwia5TbvNbSLk472").equalTo("Alex")`.

Ok fine i got the result of 2 tracks id [703486, 704875]. But the problem is i also got the John in 703486 result. So if i could have one million likes on this track i will have to retrive all likers :-(. So any one have solution how to solve this problem. Or only i can get the track id without all likers values ?

if there is no solution so unfortunately i have to switch to relational database :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have another node such as `user-tracks` to keep tracks which are liked by user.

```
user-tracks
   - AXweXLKIQiQYmwia5TbvNbSLk472 // userId
      - 703486 // track which user liked
```

Comment: Yeah i also think about this and may be this is the final solution. Ok thanx now i am going to implement this one.